I don't know how to populate mongoose with typescript

I Know how to populate mongoose with javascript but as a new typescript user i dont know how to populate mongoose with typescript...I have tried to read the documentation but i don't get i;;

import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import { TAcademicDepartment } from './academicDepartment.interface';
import { TAcademicFaculty } from '../acdemicFaculty/academicFaculty.interface';

const academicDepartmentSchema = new Schema<TAcademicDepartment>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    academicFaculty: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'AcademicFaculty',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

academicDepartmentSchema.pre(/^find/, async function(next) {

    this.populate<{ academicFaculty: TAcademicFaculty }>('academicFaculty')

  next()
})

export const AcademicDepartment = model<TAcademicDepartment>(
  'AcademicDepartment',
  academicDepartmentSchema,
);

export type TAcademicFaculty = {
  name: string;

};

when i use the code then i got something like this
│   E  This expression is not callable. typescript (2349) [45, 8]
│        Each member of the union type '{ <Paths = {}>(path: string | PopulateOptions | (string | PopulateOptions)[]): Promise<MergeType<Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<TAcademicDepartment>> & FlatRecord<...> & { ...; }, Paths>>; <Paths = {}>(path: string, select?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined, model?: Model<...> | undefined, match?: AnyObject | u...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
│
I tried to understand the mongoose documentation with typescript but i cant get it..
Or is there any other way so that when i use findById or find or findOne then i could get the reference data by using middleware?
thanks a lot for your help
